# ORACLE/SQL - Joining 3 tables that aren't all interconnected

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need help joining 3 tables where they are not all interconnected

So lets say I have tables A, B, C

here are the relations

A.type = B.type

A.model = C.model

What I need to do is inner join A and B and return all the matched A records.  Next I need to pull the records from C that match on the prior join.

Or in other words all the records in C that are in A where A is in B

Hope that makes sense.  Sorry for no data examples.

I have tried this

```
select
    c.*
from
    c, a, b
where
    c.model_ = a.model_
    and a.type_ = b.type_
```

but receive this message 'Errors: Query has MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN. You must correct where-clause to properly join tables in the select statement.'

Comment: That's not an Oracle error. In fact, a "MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN" isn't an "error" per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a matter of style but in my opinion ansi style joins make this much clearer:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM c
JOIN a ON a.model = c.model
JOIN b on b.type = a.type
```

In case you have multiple matching elements in a or b, this query will return duplicates. You can either add a DISTINCT or rewrite it as an EXISTS query:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM a
              JOIN b ON b.type = a.type
              WHERE a.model = c.model)
```

I think this should also give the same result, as long as there are no NULL values in model:

```
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.model IN (SELECT a.model
                  FROM a
                  JOIN b ON b.type = a.type)
```

Comment: style makes the difference between hard to spot mistakes and easy to spot mistakes.   I like the JOINs - it shows what you mean explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

simply also join to C with an AND condition

Answer (score 0):

Without the data samples, it is difficult to understand the actual problem and validate the query.

did you try..

```
Select c.*
   from a,b,c
    where a.type = b.type
      and a.model = c.model;
```

Are your losing some records or seeing extra records that you don't expect to see?

The above query will only give you records in c that are in a and where a records match the criterion in b.

Comment: updated my original post with my attempt and the error I see, could it be my ordering of the tables and how the joins are applied?

Comment: is this the actual error that you see.? (is there an ORA- number). Also, are a,b,c tables/ are they views with their own underlying queries..?

Comment: unfortunately that error is produced by our web based tool and thats all I have.  None of the tables are views.